# I cannot use "PermutationImportance"

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, eli5

I'm trying to use the permutation importance of eli5 to check the importance of the variables.
But I get the following error.

```
perm = PermutationImportance(model, random_state=1, scoring=mae_scorer)
perm.fit([X_test, X_spec_test], y_test)
```

**ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (2079,20,28,2) into shape (2079)**

This model inserts an Dense layer in the middle of the CNN, so we pass two inputs in an array（[X_test, X_spec_test]）.
Normal training and validation can be done with the following code without any problems.

```
fit = model.fit([X_train, X_spec_train], y_train, epochs=epochs, batch_size=batch_size, validation_data = ([X_test, X_spec_test], y_test), verbose=1)
y_train_pred = model.predict([X_train, X_spec_train])
```

The form of each variable is as follows:

X_test.shape is (2079, 20, 28, 2)

X_spec_test.shape is (2079, 45)

y_test.shape is (2079,)

The input layer of the model is defined as follows.

```
input1 = Input(shape=(X_train.shape[1], X_train.shape[2], X_train.shape[3]]))
input2 = Input(shape=(X_spec_trainshape[1],))
```

How do I get rid of the error?

Comment: Okay; do those shapes actually make sense? Should the operation be possible with data of those shapes, according to your understanding of the theory? I have no idea, but it comes across like you really have a question about the underlying theory, rather than about writing the code.

Comment: This code should work according to my understanding of this method, but couldn't work.
I would like to know how to write a code...
By the way, I referred to a below information.

https://www.kaggle.com/dansbecker/permutation-importance